# C: Error: unkown type name 'struct elements'

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I try to compile my c program but i get this errors 4 times in every single function that i have. The program that i wrote is a basic student management project. The first file is the main function, the second is all the functions and the third is the "student.h" file that contains all the declerations. I store the details of the students in a doubly linked list. Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "studentpro.h"
#define MAXSTRING 50

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  student st;
  int choice = 100;
  do{
    printMenu();
    scanf("%d",&choice);

    switch (choice){
      case 1:
         printf("Please Wait...\n");
         sleep(1);
         //list load(char *filename);
         break;
      case 2: printf("Please Wait...\n");
         sleep(1);
         //void save(char *filename, list l);
         break;
  case 3: printf("Please Wait...\n");
     sleep(1);
     
     printf("Enter name of new student: \n");
     scanf("%s\n", &st.name);
     
     printf("Enter ID of new student: \n");
     scanf("%d\n", &st.id);
      
     int addStudent(student st, list l);
     break;
  case 4: printf("Please Wait...\n");
     sleep(1);
     //student *findstudent(int id, list l);
     break;
  case 5: printf("Please Wait...\n");
     sleep(1);
     //int deleteStudent(student st, list l);
     break;
  case 6: printf("Please Wait...\n");
     sleep(1);
     //int update Student(student st, list l);
     break;
  case 7: printf("Exiting...Please Wait...\n");
     sleep(1);
     break;
  default: printf("Wrong Choice. Enter again\n");
     break;
    }
  }while (choice !=7);
}
```

...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void printMenu(){
  printf("Menu\n");
  printf("1.List Students\n");
  printf("2.Save Students in a File\n");
  printf("3.Add a Student\n");
  printf("4.Search a Student\n");
  printf("5.Delete a Student\n");
  printf("6.Update a Student\n");
  printf("7.Exit\n");
}

void print(student st){
  printf("Name of the student: %s\n", st.name);
  printf("ID of the student: %d\n", id.name);
}

void printstudents(list l){
  struct nodeR last;
  while (node != NULL){
    print(node->data);
    last = node;
    node = node->next;
  }
}

int addStudent(student st, list l){
  struct nodeR new_node = (struct nodeR)malloc(sizeof(struct nodeR));
  new_node-> st = new data;
  new_node->next NULL;
  if (*head_ref == NULL){
    new_node ->prev = NULL;
    *head_ref = new_node;
    return 0;
  }
  while (last->next != NULL)
    last = last->next;
  last->next = new_node;
  new_node -> prev = last;
}
```

...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXSTRING 50

typedef struct{
   char name[MAXSTRING];
   int id;
}student;

student name, id;

typedef struct nodeR* node;
typedef struct listR* list;

struct nodeR{
  student data;
  node next;
  node previous;
};

struct listR{
  node head;
  node tail;
};

void printMenu();
void print(student st);
void printstudents(list l);
list load(char *filename);
void save(char *filename, list l);
int addStudent(student st, list l);
student* findStudent(int id, list l);
int deleteStudent(student st, list l);
int updateStudent(student st, list l);
```

I have 3 different files. Here are the errors that are printed when I try to execute it.

```
warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[50]’ 
[-Wformat=]
   30 |          scanf("%s\n", &st.name);
      |                 ~^     ~~~~~~~~
      |                  |     |
      |                  |     char (*)[50]
      |                  char *
studentpro.c:16:12: error: unknown type name ‘student’
   16 | void print(student st){
      |            ^~~~~~~
studentpro.c:21:20: error: unknown type name ‘list’
   21 | void printstudents(list l){
      |                    ^~~~
studentpro.c:30:16: error: unknown type name ‘student’
   30 | int addStudent(student st, list l){
      |                ^~~~~~~
studentpro.c:30:28: error: unknown type name ‘list’
   30 | int addStudent(student st, list l){
      |
```

Thank You!

Comment: Aside: Your header file is missing an `#ifndef` multiple-include guard.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s\n", &st.name);`   In C, a bare reference to an array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array. So your (effectively) asking for the address of the address.  to fix this problem, remove the `&`

Comment: regarding: `void print(student st){`  The `typedef student` is not visible at this point in the code.  The code needs to include the header file that contains the `typedef student`

Comment: regarding: `void printstudents(list l){` the `typedef list` is not visible at this point in the code.  The code needs to include the header file that contains the `typedef list`

Comment: regarding: `typedef struct{
   char name[MAXSTRING];
   int id;
}student;

student name, id;`  the `typedef student` contains the two fields 'name' and 'id'  so why have two instances of 'typedef student'

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding,  please consistently indent the code for readbility.  Note:  two spaces can/will 'disappear' when using variable width fonts.  Strongly suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level

Answer (score 2):

The header file containing the definitions of `student` and of the other structs must be `#include`d in every file in which you want to use those structs. So in this case, your second file needs to `#include` your third file.